# ¿Cómo poner las palabras de un archivo en un JSpinner? Java

Tags: java, jframe, spinner

Tengo un archivo externo con unas cuantas palabras y quisiera poner un JSpinner que mostrará esas palabras como opciones, o en su defecto algun otro objeto que tenga la misma función. Mi código que escribe el array en el archivo es el siguiente:

```
        String palabras[] = {"hola", "manzana", "leon", "castillo", "videojuego"};
        String words[] = {"hello", "apple", "lion", "castle", "videogame"};
        try {
            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter("diccionario.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
                pr.println(palabras[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                pr.println(words[i]);
            }
            pr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("No existe el fichero.");
        }
```

Las palabras se me guardan correctamentey las leo de la siguiente forma:

```
try {

            BufferedReader palabras = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("diccionario.txt"));

            //lee linea a linea
            String linea;
            while ((linea = palabras.readLine()) != null){

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println("IO ERROR");
        }
```

Si arrastro un JSpinner a mi diseño gráfico como podría asignarle las palabras que lee del archivo?

Mi Spinner está así declarado:

```
private javax.swing.JSpinner spinner;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la classe SpinnerListModel y crea un método en tu JPanel para poder actualizar la lista de tu spinner. Es decir:

Tienes tu JPanel

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JMenuBar menuBar;
JButton submit;
JButton check;
JSpinner spinner;

public String test;

public MyPanel() {

    spinner = new JSpinner();
    spinner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    add(spinner);
}

public void actualizeSpinnerModel(SpinnerModel m)
{
    this.spinner.setModel(m);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.drawRect(200, 200, 50, 50);
}


}
```

Y por otro lado en el bucle donde lees las palabras del fichero, añades cada linea a un objeto tipo ArrayList parametrizada como String. Finalmente pasas dicho ArrayList a un array con el método toArray el cual te devuelve un Object[] y el cual puedes utilizar sin problemas en actualiazeSpinModel de tu objeto myPanel.

Algo así:

```
    final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 640;
    final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = DEFAULT_WIDTH /12*9;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("A1");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH,DEFAULT_HEIGHT));
    frame.requestFocus();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);

ArrayList<String> readedWords = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        BufferedReader palabras = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        //lee linea a linea
        String linea;
        while ((linea = palabras.readLine()) != null){
            readedWords.add(linea);
        }
        return readedWords.toArray();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("IO ERROR");
        return null;
    }

    Object[] w = readedWords.toArray();

    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    panel.actualizeSpinnerModel(wModel);
    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

David.

Comment: Pero no se entonces en que parte del código pasas al spinner los valores del array, no se los estás pasando al panel?

Comment: Hola. Tu haces tu propio panel (myPanel) el cual extiende de la clase de JPanel. Tu panel (myPanel) contiene una serie de elementos gráficos, entre ellos un Spinner. Bien, como has creado tu propia clase panel puedes implementar en dicha clase los métodos que te interesen para modificar los elementos que se contienen, como por ejemplo, tu spinner con  el método actualizeSpinnerModel. No se si queda claro. Gracias

Comment: Yo estoy llamando a un método del myPanel para actulizar el contenido del spinner, si te fijas en realidad los valores del array pasan de manera indirecta al spinner, el panel no  hace nada con ellos. Esto lo hago para evitar el acceso directo al Spinner (encapsulación y ocultación de información).

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicación detallada, no entendia como lo pasabas, pero esta bien eso de encapsulación, no lo habia pensado.